# Resize image inside GADBannerView

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've added advertisements to my iOS application using AdMob. And if no advertisement is shown, I want it to be replaced with an image, like this:

```
        //Request Advertisement
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    
    //Set up advertisement
    advertisementBanner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-7225493999040026/4779408290"
    advertisementBanner.rootViewController = self
    advertisementBanner.delegate = self
    advertisementBanner.load(request)
    
    //If advertisement does not load, add this.
    advertisementBanner.backgroundColor = UIColor (patternImage:UIImage (named: "adBanner1.png")!)
    advertisementBanner.contentMode =  UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
```

I've added .scaleAspectFill programmatically and using the GUI, but still doesn't change the size of the image. I created an image that's exactly the same size as the GADBannerView, but it still cutting off a bit.

The result is like this: [img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8MU9.png)

And as you can see it's not covering the whole. (It starts repeating itself)

How can I add an image inside an advertisement banner if no ads is shown? And make it cover the whole view? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you don't wanna place anything inside the container of your banner view. I've worked on lots of projects with Admob, but this one, placing stuff like image in a banner view container got me thinking if this would violate Admob's ToS. Like I said, ideally you would hide the banner view if there's no ads received (e.g. failure of loading ad).

But if you insist that you must do what you wanna do, I think the best way is that set the imageView's `contentMode` to `scaleAspectFit` instead. Because `scaleAspectFill` is much more complicated, for instance, think of how iPhones differ in width size. Also, look at the banner view itself, it's I believe set to `scaleAspectFit`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried all of the contentModes, but it dosnt make any different. Well, how can I hide the view then?

Comment: You have multiple options. Set its `isHidden` property to `true` of course. And you can adjust the vertical constraint to hide it from the screen.